# Search across multiple nodes in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to create a search Box for different categories like car,bike
here is my database structure [image]

the code I wrote for retrieving data

```
        function AllDataSearch(searchBoxInput) {
      firebase.database().ref('motorcycle').startAt(searchBoxInput).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        showData(snapshot.val());
        console.log("All Data Search1:", snapshot.val(),showData(snapshot.val()));
      });
      firebase.database().ref('cars').startAt(searchBoxInput).orderByChild('title').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        console.log("All Data Search2:", snapshot.val());
      });
      firebase.database().ref('electricappliances').startAt(searchBoxInput).orderByChild('title').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        console.log("All Data Search3:", snapshot.val());
      });
      firebase.database().ref('mobiles').startAt(searchBoxInput).orderByChild('title').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        console.log("All Data Search4:", snapshot.val());
      });
    }
```

but when I try to run this code I get the following error

> [2018-07-10T20:01:19.574Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "title" at /all to your security rules for better performance.

I have also added **".indexOn"** in the rules section of firebase database as the error suggests,see picture below.

[image]

but the error does'nt go, is there any other way to search across multiple nodes in firebase database or remove this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The warning says that you should add an index to `/all`. There is no `/all` in your rules. Since the code you shared doesn't query `/all`, it seems you have another place in your query where you query that node. The solution is to add an index for `title` to `/all` too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please tell me how can I add index to /all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning says that you should add an index to `/all`. There is no `/all` in your rules. Since the code you shared doesn't query `/all`, it seems you have another place in your query where you query that node. The solution is to add an index for title to `/all` too, so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...,
    "all": {
      ".indexOn": "title"
    }
  }
}
```